# Which one is better for getting accurate performance counte:DateTime or Stopwatch?

Tags: c#

I am aware of DateTime and Stopwatch class,but I am little bit confused.I just wanted to know that which one is better and why?

Comment: I dont think you could say either is one is better than the other. They are completely different, DateTime is just a data type to represent a date & time. Stopwatch is from System.Diagnostics designed for timing how long your function calls take. Do you have a certain purpose in mind?

Comment: @Sean: see the title of the question

Comment: @Sean:I wanted to know which one is better for measuring the performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Stopwatch` class is designed for measuring the duration of an operation.

The `DateTime` struct is designed to hold a date value.

Answer (score 6):

The `Stopwatch` class uses a high-resolution timer which is appropriate for performing (certain) benchmarking tests. As the name implies, it measures elapsed time (i.e. mimics a real-life stopwatch.)

`DateTime` is appropriate for keeping track of *date*s and *time*s; do not use it for benchmarking.

Comment: +1 for the answer.I have one question what do you mean by **high-resolution**

Comment: @geek I mean that the interval between "ticks" of the timer is low, so that it can represent more distinct points in time between two end-points.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is for representing dates and times. `Stopwatch` is for measuring how long something took. `Stopwatch` is highly precise, and highly accurate while `DateTime` is not. Therefore, `Stopwatch` is clearly the right chose to measure how long something took.

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft, Stopwatch is more accurate for measuring elapsed time.

Datetime is a class used for date and time operations.

[Stopwatch Class (System.Diagnostics) - MSDN](http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx&rct=j&q=msdn%20stopwatch&ei=VgsOTs6RD4nrgQe1rNjWDQ&usg=AFQjCNFoy1iczLafi91JqYTgzhCwwOTHuw&sig2=lG7f6BS4PExgStY7YFaOBA)